# How to send email to multiple recipients on creation of new node using rules module?

Tags: rules

I have created one node type.
Now, I want to send an email to multiple recipients on creation of new node using rules module.

Comment: Please followup with problems on sending email as a new question (but search first to see if it has been addressed), or consider using chat.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To send emails to multiple persons on creating a new node, you have to create a new rule and follow these steps :

1. Create an event `After saving a new content type` and then select that particular content type.
2. After that add an action from `Select the action to add` select list and choose `Send Email`.
3. After that you can add multiple email ids in the `To` textarea separated by comma and space like this :

   first_email@mail.com, second@mail.com, third@mail.com

Comment: i tried this, but this is giving me following error "Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists."

Comment: To enable e-mail services from your local, you have to add and enable a module SMTP module to do this.

Comment: i am not on local server, i am on live server. I am adding email addresses in "To textarea" not in "From textarea"

Comment: Check the logs for what the real error is.